# How to interpret convergence in probability of the number of heads in a sequence of coin tosses?

Tags: probability

Suppose I toss a fair coin infinitely many times. Let $A_n$ denote the event that the $n$th toss is heads, and suppose the $A_n$ are independent and $P(A_n) = p = 1/2$, and let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1_{A_i}$ be the number of heads in the first n tosses. The law of averages states that for each $\epsilon > 0$ $$P(p - \epsilon \le n^{-1}S_n \le p + \epsilon) \to 1$$ as $n \to \infty$.

On pg. 33 of their book Grimmet and Stirzaker write the following about the interpretation of the above statement:

> it is not true that, in a ‘typical’ sequence of tosses of a fair coin, that heads outnumber tails about one-half of the time.

Could someone please explain why this is not true? I think the idea is that just because the ratio of heads approaches $1/2$, this doesn’t mean that the ratio of heads to tails must always alternate between being above and below $1$. For example, $\omega = H, H, T, H, T, H, T, H, T, \cdots$ has $n^{-1}S_n(\omega) \to 1/2$ but the ratio of heads to tails is always above 1. Is this related to ergodicity?

Comment: I think what the authors mean is that it's unlikely to have Head for 60% of the outcomes. Note that 60/40 = 1.5.

Comment: Could you please expand on this? I’m not sure what you mean. How does this follow from the above?